# В чем отличие Pull Request от MergeRequest?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Пользовался различными репозиториями(GitHub,Bitbucket,GitLab). В каждом репозитории одно и тоже действие называется по разному. В чем отличие Pull Request от MergeRequest? Почему называются Pull Request и MergeRequest? Может это из-за того что под капотом разные команды?

Comment: `pull`, по умолчанию, приблизительно равен `fetch`+`merge`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Merge Request и Pull Request это один и тот же функционал, который в разных репозитариях просто называется по разному, об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/09/29/gitlab-flow/).
И то и другое обозначает один и тот же процесс, в GitHub и Bitbucket называют операцию pull request, потому что первое действие, которое совершит человек, который будет вливать себе правки из request это git pull, тогда как GitLab и Gitorious называют это действие merge request, потому что финальным действием будет слияние изменений (git merge)

Answer (score 22):

Если я не ошибаюсь, под капотом - одно и то же. `GitLab` оперирует `Merge Request`, GitHub - `Pull Request`. Разница скорее смысловая, ведь `GitLab` предназначен больше для использования внутри компании, `GitHub` - опенсорс. Отсюда вытекает логика: внутри компании мы создаем запрос "Я вот наделал, хочу свою ветку залить в мастер\девелоп\етц". А на гитхаб - "Я вот тут ваш продукт усовершенствовал, заберите-ка то чего я наделал".